# How do I determine if an image has been photoshopped?

Tags: image-manipulation, photoshop

Does anyone know how to tell if an image has been photoshopped?

*edit* Specifically, I want to determine if regions or pixels in the image have been altered by photoshop.  I'm not as interested in finding errors in the photoshop job (missing shadows, errors in reflections, etc)

I seem to remember something like a high-pass filter that you could use that would determine the noise levels.  Edited regions would have less noise, or at least changes in noise.  I'm having a hard time finding information on this or other approaches.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this website to check if an image is photoshopped or edited:
http://imageedited.com

Answer (score 4):

[HOWTO spot a photoshop job](http://www.boingboing.net/2008/06/02/howto-spot-a-photosh.html)
[How To Tell If A JPG Image Has Been Photoshopped (Windows)](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tell-if-that-jpg-has-been-altered-with-jpegsnoop-windows/)

Google is your friend for many relevant results.

Comment: Thanks! I did a horrible job of asking that question.  I'm really trying to understand how a photo has been altered deceptively.   Quantitative methods to classify pixels or regions of pixels as different in nature from the others (e.g. analyzing noise, or cross-correlations for repeating structures) are what I was hoping for.  Know of any?

Answer (score 4):

maybe fotoforensic works. its an online program to compare the no of times a photo has been compressed. the no differs for the original image and the added image. hope it helps u.
http://fotoforensics.com

Answer (score 0):

I would give a try with error level analysis:
http://www.errorlevelanalysis.com/
Follow the links on that site and maybe get in contact with the author, I'm sure they can give you the needed pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you have to check is the properties of the file.
If it was last save via photoshop, there should be a meta data under "details" -> "origin" -> "program name". :)